# Showing label after UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to show a label after the user dragged an image down. The problem is that the label won't show after. Everything else works fine but only the label doesn't work. I've tried to find a solution for a couple hours but I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Function that is called on UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
func pullDownView(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if(gesture.state == .changed) {
        if(iconImage.center.y - (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2) < view.frame.size.height / 3) {
            let translationY = gesture.translation(in: view).y
            iconImage.center.y += translationY

            gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: view)
            iconImage.updateConstraints()
        }else{
            iconImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            iconImage.center.y = (view.frame.size.height / 3) + (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2)
            iconImage.updateConstraints()
        }
    }

    if(gesture.state == .cancelled || gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .failed) {
        if(iconImage.center.y - (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2) >= view.frame.size.height / 6) {
            if(iconImage.center.y != (view.frame.size.height / 3) + (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2)) {
                iconImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                iconImage.center.y = (view.frame.size.height / 3) + (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2)
                iconImage.updateConstraints()

                getAccounts()
            }
        }else{
            iconImage.center.y = view.frame.size.height / 2
            iconImage.updateConstraints()
        }
    }
}

func getAccounts() {
    noAccountsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    noAccountsLabel.text = "No accounts found!"
    noAccountsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 20)
    noAccountsLabel.textAlignment = .center
    noAccountsLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: noAccountsLabel.frame.size.height * 2)

    view.addSubview(noAccountsLabel)
}
```

Thanks for helping!
Steff.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to ensure the obvious.. the text color isn't the same as the background is it?

Comment: and you are sure that the block is being called, the block that has `getAccounts`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to print a string out and it worked fine. And the text color isn't the same, tried to change it but still doesn't work.

Comment: where is `noAccountsLabel` created? Is that an IBOutlet?

Comment: No, It's just an empty label - var noAccountsLabel = UILabel() - it's above viewDidLoad()

Comment: Just checking the obvious... (1) Are you using Auto layout? I'm only seeing frame coordinates for the label. (2) Speaking of that, try just setting the frame of the UILabel() you declared instead of initing another UILabel. That syntax feels wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
func getAccounts() {
  let noAccountsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
  noAccountsLabel.text = "No accounts found!"
  noAccountsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 20)
  noAccountsLabel.textAlignment = .center
  noAccountsLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: noAccountsLabel.frame.size.height * 2)

  view.addSubview(noAccountsLabel)
}
```

Worked for me.

PS: I may have done the logic wrong here, but you can use `guard` regardless to clear up some `if` statements:

```
guard gesture.state == .cancelled || gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .failed else  { return }

guard (iconImage.center.y - (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2) >= view.frame.size.height / 6) else { return }

if(iconImage.center.y != (view.frame.size.height / 3) + (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2)) {
  iconImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
  iconImage.center.y = (view.frame.size.height / 3) + (iconImage.frame.size.height / 2)
  iconImage.updateConstraints()

  getAccounts()
}
```

Comment: I've found a solution to display the label but now the iconImage jumps back  to the place it was before, do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Pretty stupid but I forgot that I already had "Accounts" in user defaults and that's the reason why the label didn't show up. But when the label display, the iconImage jumps back to it's old place.

Comment: try putting `getAccounts` above the icon image code in your block

Comment: Still doesn't work, I think it's something with the constraints of the iconImage, is that possible?

Comment: I haven't worked much with constraints, but it would appear that is the issue, if it jumps around when new things are added to the screen. You might need to post a new question here :)

Comment: I'll try to add the constraints programmatically instead of in the storyboard. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: PS, you can use `guard` to get rid of some of those `if` statements (it makes following along a bit difficult at first). See my updated answer for the tip.

Comment: @stefffeyens Also, if you found my answer or comments useful, I do appreciate upvotes ^-^()